# preg_match() $pattern issues with format

Tags: php

I'm looking at the preg_match instructions, but struggling to gather together what I need to only allow a certain few characters to be used, and how to implement that into the pattern format

```
                        if(preg_match('[0-9.$M]', $_POST['budget']) === true) {
                            $errors = 'no illegal';
                        } else {
                            //Illegal character in budget
                            $errors = 'illegal';
                        }
```

But I've realized that for one that doesn't work for this combination
`0123456789$M.` as well as that it will not function as I want it to even if I get it to work. as I need to check the $_POST['budget'] and be sure it's in the correct format before moving on with it. It can ONLY contain the characters I've put forward, anything else will create a pretty big mess.

So far, I've had javascript change any entries, but if that is disabled then they can put in whatever they please.

So I need is pseudo

```
if (preg_match($allowed_characters, $_POST['budget'] === true && DOESNT CONTAIN ANY OTHER CHARACTERS) {
    //No illegal characters
} else {
    //Illegal characters!!
}
```

Comment: You forgot the `/delimiters/`.

Comment: Immediate downvote, nice..

Comment: -shrugs- it's a typo question. Typo questions get downvoted and closevoted.

Comment: It's not a typo, if you read the full question, it is asking how to make sure the correct characters are there, and how to not allow any characters that could be there as well..?

Comment: And I'm also struggling with the actual pattern, you say delimiters but is that `/[0-9.$M]/` or `[/0-9/./$/M]` or..?

Comment: @DanielWatson Try `^[0-9.$M]*$` or `^[0-9.$M]+$` depending on what you want.

Comment: You appear to lack a basic understanding of regexes... just Google for any simple tutorial, or better still [check the docs](http://php.net/pcre).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) preg_match returns INT or BOOL false.

2) Your pattern is not valid for preg_match

should be something like:

```
if(preg_match('/[^0-9\.\$M]+/', '0123456789$M.')) {
    $errors = 'illegal';
} else {                        
    $errors = 'no illegal';
}
```